# Looking for Complete Online Collection of the Sermons of German Priest, Fr. Franz Hunolt, S.J

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, priests, sermon

From Wikipedia:

Hunolt's idea was to treat the entire field of morals in his sermons thoroughly and completely. Each of the six volumes contains seventy-two sermons, and the various divisions in each volume are indicated by sub-titles, such as "The Christian Attitude towards Life"; "The Wicked Christian"; "The Penitent Christian"; "The Good Christian"; "The Last End of Christians"; "The Christian's Model". This prodigious mass of material is distributed most appropriately over the entire ecclesiastical year. How popular, and at the same time profound, Hunolt's expositions are, is best proved by the fact that numerous excerpts are included in all anthologies and textbooks of religious rhetoric as standard.

A competent critic *(Kraus)* has eulogized Hunolt's sermons in the following words: **"At a time when German pulpit oratory had degenerated into utter bad taste and brainless insipidity, these sermons are distinguished by noble simplicity, pure Christian sentiment, and genuine apostolic ideas no less than by the felicitous use of Holy Writ, abundance of thought and pregnant language."**

The following provides 3 of the (apparently) 12 volumes: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Hunolt_Sermons

QUESTION: Does anyone know of a more extensive (preferably complete) collection of Fr. Humolt's sermons (in English; German O.K.) that I may freely access online?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the 12 volumes are located here: https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/100027000 (HathiTrust Digital Library).